# Difference of two cell arrays of strings in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I have a cell array like

```
a={'potential'; 'impact'; 'of'; 'stranded'; 'assets'; 'and'; 'other'; 'necessary'; 'regulatory'; 'approvals'; 'assets'}
```

and want to subtract from it an array like b={'a'; 'and'; 'of'; 'my'; '#'}.

Using setdiff(a,b) sorts my array after the difference is computed. What I want is to eliminate from a all the elements present in b without sorting a. Also the repetitions should be preserved, for eg. 'assets' in array a should appear at two locations in final array.

The following code I am using does the job:

```
for i = 1:length(b)
    tf = ~strcmp(b(i),a)
    a = a(tf,:)
end
```

But the problem is that array b contains more than 200 string elements which slows down my code considerably. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tf = ismember(a,b);
a = a(~tf)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EDU>> a

a =     
    'potential'
    'impact'
    'of'
    'stranded'
    'assets'
    'and'
    'other'
    'necessary'
    'regulatory'
    'approvals'
    'assets'

EDU>> b

b = 

    'a'
    'and'
    'of'
    'my'
    '#'

 [I,J]=setdiff(a,b);
```

Now do

```
EDU>> a(sort(J),:)

ans = 

    'potential'
    'impact'
    'stranded'
    'other'
    'necessary'
    'regulatory'
    'approvals'
    'assets'
```

Comment: the problem with this solution is that element 'assets' appear at two positions in the original cell array. But in the final array the repetitions are eliminated and 'assets' appears only once. While I want that the repeated elements should be preserved in their original positions.

Comment: OK, good point. You said you wanted the duplicates kept. I overlooked that part.